# Why cooked food is not to be eaten on holi before holika dahan?

Tags: scripture, festivals

What is the significance behind it and does it has foundation of scriptural reference? Why cooked food is eaten only after holika dahan?

Comment: I don't think this is a pan-Hinduism thing. Maybe a local custom, or at best based on local beliefs. As it is, there are very few references to Holika-dahan. Let alone, (m)any rules regarding that.